# Transforming a variable coefficient linear ODE into a constant coefficient ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am giving this question below:

[image]

I am pretty stumped on a) - I have only managed to do the basic task of replacing all of the x variables by t^2.

What I am confused about is, how do I go about the derivatives of y with respect to x? How can I "change" this derivative such that it is with respect to t? Or, is it ok to leave it as it is?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$. So in your case, that is $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2t\frac{dy}{dx}$ i.e. $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2t}\frac{dy}{dt}$

For higher order derivatives, differentiate this equation in $t$ using the product rule.

E.g. $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} $

$= \frac{d^2y}{dxdt}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$

$= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$

So in your case this is $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = 4t^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 2\frac{dy}{dx}$

So our ODE is: $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} +9y = 0$.